# Sometimes Hibernate can not get connection by C3P0

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, c3p0

I have a project use Struts2+hibernate3(c3p0),

Following is my C3P0 configuration

```
    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">2</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">15</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_idle_time">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">100</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">select 1 from dual</property>
    <property name="automaticTestTable">Test</property>
    <!-- <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property> -->

    <property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnectForPools">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.is-connection-validation-required">true</property>
```

My database is mysql and I can not config it (in cloud)

My problem is some time I got following message

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:126)
at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:114)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:142)
at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:85)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1354)
at com.rh.ws.getAllMessageAction.getAllMessage(getAllMessageAction.java:42)
... 86 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:690)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider.getConnection(C3P0ConnectionProvider.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    ... 91 more
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1422)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:606)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:526)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:756)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:683)
```

The wait_timeout is 30s in my database(mysql) and it's can not change.

I try to set the max_idle_time to 20 and I discover it doesn't work.

Do I need close the connection every time? or just close the session is fine?

Comment: I check a lot of sample just close session, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you close a Session it will automatically close the underlying connection. You should also commit the Hibernate Transaction on success and rollback on failure. This will ensure that the database transaction is properly terminated.

If you don't close teh Hibernate Session, then the JDBC connection won't be released. So when all **hibernate.c3p0.max_size** are being in use, you'll soon get the connection acquire connection exception.

One other cause might be due to very long running queries. Check your queries as well.

Make sure:

```
<prop key="hibernate.c3p0.checkoutTimeout">30</prop>
```

has an enough connection acquire timeout value.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I got it, and I have check the provider document again, It suggested use short connect mode. :(